# PostgreSQL Trigger to keep track of table changes

Tags: postgresql, trigger, change-tracking

I am trying to create a trigger (Postgres 9.6) to track changes made to a table. This is my approach:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION taxon_history() RETURNS trigger AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
        INSERT INTO history.taxon(operacao, "data", tecnico, original_oid, taxon)
        VALUES ('DELETE', current_timestamp, current_user, old.oid, old.taxon);
        RETURN old;

    ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
        INSERT INTO history.taxon(operacao, "data", tecnico, original_oid, taxon)
        VALUES ('DELETE', current_timestamp, current_user, old.oid, old.taxon);
        RETURN old;

    ELSIF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        INSERT INTO history.taxon(operacao, "data", tecnico, original_oid, taxon)
        VALUES ('INSERT', current_timestamp, current_user, new.oid, new.taxon);
        RETURN old;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER history_taxon
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON taxon
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE taxon_history();
```

However when something changes in the `(public).taxon` table, no record is added to the `history.taxon` table. I also don´t get any error message so I am in the dark on why nothing is happening. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me.  When TG_OP is UPDATE, you are inserting the string "DELETE" into the history table.  Which is confusing, to be sure, but it does work.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, it should be UPDATE of course. Thanks for testing it. In that case I assume that there is some other constraint that is playing a role.

Comment: In the end I solved this through ´Divide and conquer´. I split the trigger into three parts and now it works:

Answer (score 1):

For the archive and someone landing here through search, I have updated the answer of [lisdengard](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/149327/lisdengard) to have a general approach on the topic using Postgresql 11 (and 13):

```
create table MY_journal ( like   histories );
-- enum:
--   I insert
--   D delete
--   U update (NEW values)
--   u update (OLD values if not already in journal)
alter table MY_journal add column MY_op CHARACTER(1) NOT NULL;

-- TODO: timestamp of journaling, but
--    ROW(s.*) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ROW(OLD.*, 'U')
-- would not work then, otherwise we would have 'u' entry always
-- currently: no need for JTS as parent table has a timestamp column
-- alter table MY_journal add column MY_ts_journaling TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW NOT NULL;

-- we do not have no real Primary Key actually
create index idx_MY_journal on MY_journal ( history_id, history_ts, history_subid );

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_MY_journal() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
declare
        rec RECORD;

BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
        INSERT INTO MY_journal VALUES (OLD.*, 'D');
        RETURN OLD;

    ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
--      debugging / tracing
--      FOR rec IN SELECT * FROM MY_journal s where s.history_id = old.history_id and s.history_subid = old.history_subid and s.MY_op = 'U' LOOP
--              raise notice 'FOR 1      %',  rec;
--      END LOOP;
--      FOR rec IN SELECT * FROM MY_journal s where  ROW(s.*) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ROW(OLD.*, 'U') LOOP
--              raise notice 'FOR 2      %',  rec;
--      END LOOP;
        -- IS NOT DISTINCT FROM compares NULLs accordingly
        IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM MY_journal s where  ROW(s.*) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ROW(OLD.*, 'U') OR ROW(s.*) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ROW(OLD.*, 'I') ) THEN
                -- raise notice 'INSERT OLD %',  ROW(OLD.*, 'U');
                INSERT INTO MY_journal VALUES (OLD.*, 'u');
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO MY_journal VALUES (NEW.*, 'U');
        RETURN NEW;

    ELSIF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        INSERT INTO MY_journal VALUES (NEW.*, 'I');
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

COMMENT ON FUNCTION f_MY_journal IS 'Keep a journal of the changes in history';

CREATE TRIGGER tr_MY_journal
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON histories
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE f_MY_journal();
```

The DML and ROW() assumes, that ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN adds the new columns at the end of the row,hence, (OLD.*, 'D') a.s.o.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved this through 'Divide and conquer' - I split the trigger into three parts and now it works (though I am not sure yet why the original trigger does not work):

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION taxon_history_delete() RETURNS trigger AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
        INSERT INTO history.taxon(operacao, data, tecnico, original_oid, taxon)
        VALUES ('DELETE', current_timestamp, current_user, old.oid, old.taxon);
        RETURN old;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION taxon_history_update() RETURNS trigger AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
        INSERT INTO history.taxon(operacao, data, tecnico, original_oid, taxon)
        VALUES ('UPDATE', current_timestamp, current_user, old.oid, old.taxon);
        RETURN old;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION taxon_history_insert() RETURNS trigger AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        INSERT INTO history.taxon(operacao, data, tecnico, original_oid, taxon)
        VALUES ('INSERT', current_timestamp, current_user, new.oid, new.taxon);
        RETURN new;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create TRIGGER taxon_history_delete
Before DELETE ON taxon
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE taxon_history_delete();

create TRIGGER taxon_history_update
Before UPDATE ON taxon
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE taxon_history_update();

create TRIGGER taxon_history_insert
AFTER INSERT ON taxon
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE taxon_history_insert();
```

Comment: You don't need the `IF` statements any more with that structure. But I don't understand either why your initial trigger didn't work